# How to create a React Web application connected to Mongo, Node which shows Streak, Badges etc.?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

So I'm designing this application which would show popup badges when a task is completed. Say for example, a streak badge would be displayed if a user continuously watches 3 videos. So how do I monitor for these changes and trigger badges validation in React given that I would have the list of badges and description in mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess there is no straightforward answer for this kind of problem. What I would do is monitor all these actions that results in badges. For example when a user finishes watching a video I would make a post request to a server (or use mutation if you use graphql) that looks like this:

```
{
  user_id: "123abc",
  video_id: "456def",
  finisheded_at: <timestamp or date object>
}
```

(of course this is protected route)
then store that data and decide whether user earned a badge. Then show info about earned badge either with websocket or simply waiting for request to finish.

Like I said there is no straightforward answer. Every kind of action requires different logic for checking whether user earned a badge.